# Angular2 DecimalPipe with input type="number"

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

On one hand I have in my component:

```
public test:number = 1000;
```

On another hand, I have created a piece of view this way:

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="test | number:'1.0-1'" />
```

As soon as the property "test" is less than 1000, the input displays the value. Whenever it reaches 1000 and more, this value is not displayed anymore in the input.

Here is a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pFThNc1JNxfsnzJK9nCV

Is there something I missed? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `Input` with type `number` doesn't allow to pass text with comma

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer from yurzui: "Input with type number doesn't allow to pass text with comma"